# not able to pass value through link and router react js

Tags: reactjs

i am tring to pass a date to  `<CDietOverview />`

```
               <TabPanel>
                 <Dietracker dataFromParent={date} />
                 <Link
                   to={{
                     pathname: "/cdiet",
                     state: { date },
                   }}
                 >
                   <button onClick={this.closeTabBox}>edit</button>
                 </Link>
               </TabPanel>
```

this is my route

```
           <Route path="/cdiet">
              <CDietOverview />
            </Route>
```

i already have some data loading in props with that data i also want to load the date

```
 componentDidMount() {
    let message = this.props.location.state; //state is undefined
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };

 }
```

the date is undefined when i try to access it with  `this.props.location.state`

also i want only to pass date when i click on the edit button in my link

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `Link`. Do this,

```
<Link
    to={{
    pathname: "/cdiet",
    state: { value: date },
    }}
>
```

Use `value` in the state object.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Comment: Where are you getting the date from ?

Comment: dataFromParent={date}

Comment: constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { isClose: true };
    this.closeTabBox = this.closeTabBox.bind(this);
    date = this.props.dataFromParent;
  }

Comment: Is there a date state present in the component?

Comment: intialy no only when i click on a calnder date is passed

Answer (score 0):

date pass in objects parameter

```
<TabPanel>
  <Dietracker dataFromParent={date} />
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: "/cdiet",
      state: { date: date },
    }}
  >
    <button onClick={this.closeTabBox}>edit</button>
  </Link>
</TabPanel>
```

Comment: iam getting
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Comment: whenever you access this state pass component inside `withRouter(component)`.

Comment: can u explain plse i did not undersatnd

Comment: in your case add this one on the last snippet code component.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the component in which you want to use `location.state` with [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/withRouter)

example

```
export default withRouter(YourComponent); // component in which you want location.state
```

Comment: which file should i write this

Comment: inside `CDietOverview`,

Comment: `export default withRouter(CDietOverview);`